# Executing mysql scripts tasks on (on-premise linux agent) mysql server using Azure DevOps Release pipeline?

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-devops

I have configured Azure Release pipeline for my deployment. But I want to run Mysql scripts on Mysql Sever using azure devops tasks, can someone help me if there is a best way to run the scripts ?

0- what task should I use from azure marketplace ?
1- should I run all scripts in one task or each script as a separate task ?
2- how to wait while script is running ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[MySQL Toolkit for Windows](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=daporo.mysql-toolkit-win&targetId=8b5aa46a-618f-4eee-b902-48c215242e3e) is a VSTS / TFS extension and contains helpful tasks for build and release definition for MySQL servers. You can run ad-hoc MySQL command, script or scripts collection on Windows Agents including Windows Hosted Agents (Linux Agents not supported).

In addition, you can add a step to run a [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops)/[batch script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/batch-script?view=azure-devops) to execute the SQL script, and you can also [create a custom build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops) and publish it to VSTS.

BTW, you could add [PowerShell Sleep function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.1) to wait while script is running.

Update>>You could use [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy files from a source folder to a target folder using match patterns.

Comment: Hi jayaprakash, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result. Thank you.

Comment: hi wallezzi, I use Linux Agents, I need to try bash script task for Sql file. But problem with that is how would I copy sql files to mysql server from my pipeline ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it.